# WSO2 server not starting: org.wso2.carbon.server.util.BundleInfoLine.getInstance(BundleInfoLine.java:87)

Tags: java, wso2

I am not able to start the server now, yesterday it was working fine. I didn't make any changes anywhere.

The moment I type `runConsole.bat` I get error, before this edit it was working fine.

```
 at org.wso2.carbon.server.util.BundleInfoLine.getInstance(BundleInfoLine.java:87)
 at org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer.processBundlesInfoFile(DropinsBundleDeployer.java:198)
 at org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer.perform(DropinsBundleDeployer.java:107)
 at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.invokeExtensions(Main.java:146)
 at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.main(Main.java:92)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:70)
 at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:51)
```

Comment: Which WSO2 product is this?

Comment: I have downloaded this file from WSO2  website `wso2ei-windows-installer-x64-6.4.0.msi` It gave me two folders - `APIManager` and `EnterpriseIntegrator` . I have set up them to run as a console `runConsole.bat`. API Manager verision is 2.6.0 and EI is 6.4.0

Answer (score 1):

Please restart the carbon.bat file, then try to start the server.